# Internal NLB behind Route 53 only accessible on port 80 and 443

Tags: amazon-elb, aws-nlb

I have an internal NLB that listens on 443 and custom port (say 7273).  NLB Security group allows all TCP traffic (to ensure this is not an issue)

Route 53 CNAME (say example.com) is mapped to NLB CNAME.

NLB has 3 listeners:

| Listener port | Target group port | Behaviour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | 7273 | Reachable as https://example.com:80 |
| 443 | 8080 | Reachable as https://example.com |
| 7273 | 7273 | Not reachable from local machine as https://example.com:7273, works when using a bastion box in same AWS account |

Can internal load balancer be accessed only on 80 and 443 ports if behind Route53 and accessed via Route53 URL?

https://example.com:7273 should be accessible

Comment: "NLB Security group allows all TCP traffic (to ensure this is not an issue)" this is silly.  What, do you think the security group or NLB port settings have an off-by-one error bug?  Opening ports you're not using has no effect on the ports you are using.  Debugging this will take stepping through all the various settings for the security groups at the NLB and listener, health checks, etc.  We can't really help with that as we don't have access to AWS.

Comment: @erik258, I opened all ports on NLG SG to rule out that possibility. But then allowing port 80, 443, and 7273 on same CIDR doesn't works on 7273 (or any other) except 80 and 443.

This is internal NLB behind Route53, all I have is Route 53 > NLB > EC2